# SAXParseException; The entity "CC" was referenced, but not declared

Tags: xml, parsing, ascii, symbols

Referencing to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986450/is-there-a-mistake-in-adding-string-to-arraylist) where I am using the same SAXParser code, I was trying to parse this xml document:

```
<doc>
    <str name="id">743</str>
    <str name="full_message_t">[ST] Needy has help with S&CC; cost-cutting being implemented http://t.co/Ta7Kgc3f3L</str>
    <str name="source_t">ST</str>
    <str name="news_t">Needy has help with S&CC; cost-cutting being implemented </str>
    <str name="link_t">http://t.co/Ta7Kgc3f3L</str>
    <long name="_version_">1464787947397054464</long>
</doc>
```

and I got this error

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1667; columnNumber: 62; The entity "CC" was referenced, but not declared.
```

If I am not wrong. &CC is the ASCII for copyright symbol and I assume the Parser can't read it. So may I know what is the solution for this?
In addition, I assume there might be more of these symbols. Is there some kind of import or roundabout method for the Parser to be able to read all the symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Your file is not well formed XML; XML doesn't allow you to use entity references unless they are declared (in the DTD). So in fact it's not actually an XML document.

When you get bad XML the best solution is always to work out where and when it was produced and fix the process that produced it, so that it doesn't happen again.

However, if you need to repair it, you should be able to find a DTD that contains definitions of the ISO Latin1 entities and add a reference to this DTD to the document (in  a DOCTYPE declaration) before parsing it.